# How to fix j key not working terminal 22.04.1

Tags: gnome-terminal, bug-reporting, shortcut-keys

So I reinstalled ubuntu for reasons not worth mentioning and now the 'j' key does not working in terminal at all.

The only way to get the key to function is to do one of the following:

- <kbd>Left Shift</kbd> + <kbd>j</kbd> = J
- <kbd>Left Windows</kbd> + <kbd>j</kbd> = j
- <kbd>j</kbd> = no output to the terminal

I have no clue what to do. Can someone take a few minutes with me on this to recommend some ideas I can try? I know my way around a terminal and linux in general enough to try almost anything.

Thanks guys.

Comment: Does the `j` key work inside other applications - like LibreOffice, Firefox etc.??

Comment: It seems to work everywhere but terminal.

Comment: Then I assume it's a setting or override in the terminal application somehow. Is it called "Gnome Terminal" - or which terminal application is it? You should look to troubleshoot there.

Comment: I have to check by booting back into ubuntu.. I'm on windows right now but as soon as i can i will let you know. I can tell you that on a fresh install I use the search feature and type "terminal" a black window app shows up and that's the one I am using.

Comment: Assuming you're using the terminal's default bash shell, please [edit] your question to include the output of command `bind -p | grep -w $'\152'`

Comment: Guys, I went ahead and reinstalled Jammy 22.04.1 again and now everything is working. Thanks for the effort to help me out. Sadly I cannot say what happened. It may have something to do with some of the development libraries I installed (which I have yet to reinstall up to this point),